# What HTTP Error code to return if my Json is missing a field value?

Tags: rest, http-error

For example, I have JSON like:

```
{
    "firstName":"",
    "lastName":"Gustafson",
    "dob":"1980-09-09T00:00:00.000+00:00"
}
```

If all 3 of these were required and given that above Json body is missing value for **firstName**, what HTTP error code would be considered a good fit to sent to clients from an API?

Would **400 Bad Request** be considered a "bad request" even though it is well formatted but just missing a value for **firstName**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If all 3 of these were required and given that above Json body is missing value for firstName, what HTTP error code would be considered a good fit to sent to clients from an API?

I would normally use [422 Unprocessable Content](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5.21)

> The 422 (Unprocessable Content) status code indicates that the server
> understands the content type of the request content (hence a 415
> (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request content is correct, but was unable to process
> the contained instructions.  For example, this status code can be
> sent if an XML request content contains well-formed (i.e.,
> syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous XML instructions.

403 Forbidden would also be a reasonable option.